# Communication between two UWP apps

Tags: uwp, background-task

I have two uwp apps in my solution one is appService and another is clientApp which calls appService.

I added this code in clientApp:

```
this.inventoryService = new AppServiceConnection();
this.inventoryService.AppServiceName = "com.microsoft.inventory";
this.inventoryService.PackageFamilyName ="bb1a8478-8005-46869923-e525ceaa26fc_4sz2ag3dcq60a";

var status = await this.inventoryService.OpenAsync();

if (status != AppServiceConnectionStatus.Success)
{
    button.Content = "Failed to connect";
    return;
}
```

This status seems to be AppNotInstalled. 
[Windows.ApplicationModel.AppService.AppServiceConnectionStatus.AppNotInstalled]

Could anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the app package that is hosting the app service is actually installed? Can you share the appxmanifest from that app that is declaring the app service? Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this on an emulator or debugging on the local machine? The app package may not be installed on the emulator VM.

Comment: The problem is solved. I gave the wrong packageFamilyName. As soon as I corrected the packageFamilyName it worked